# How to show multiple calendars

Tags: calendar

I am using Michael Rog's Calendar add-on with these params:

```
{% switch craft.request.getSegment(2) %}
    {% case '' %}
        {% set thisCalendar  = '2,3' %}
        {% set calendarTitle = 'Full Calendar' %}
    {% case 'mts' %}
        {% set thisCalendar  = '2' %}
        {% set calendarTitle = 'MTS Calendar' %}
    {% case 'day-school' %}
        {% set thisCalendar  = '3' %}
        {% set calendarTitle = 'Day School Calendar' %}
{% endswitch %}

{% set calendarParams = {
    dateRangeStart: 'today',
    dateRangeEnd: '+36 months',
    calendarId: thisCalendar
    } %}
```

The individual calendars are working and showing the correct entries but without a segment 2 I am only getting the events from Calendar ID 2 but not from ID 3.

If I do this:

```
    {% case '' %}
        {% set thisCalendar  = '3,2' %}
```

I get events from Calendar ID 3 but not from ID 2.

How do I get events from all calendars? Is comma separated the correct syntax? Should this be working?

Comment: Have you tried passing an array instead? Like so: `{% set thisCalendar  = [3,2] %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting comment as answer, since the suggested solution solved it:

Pass the IDs as an array instead of comma separated: `{% set thisCalendar = [3,2] %}`